# Set Cookies expiration in angular js

Tags: angularjs

When a user is logging in, I am storing the values in cookies that I received from the backend. Now I want to set the cookies' expiration to 8 hours. How can I do that?

I have done like this but I am not sure if it is correct or not

```
var expireDate = new Date();
var time = expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
$cookieStore.put('userData', record.data.profileData,{'expires':time});
```

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: 1.3.2 @GhulamMohayudin

Comment: see this link using cookieStore is not a good way to store expiry time
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/J8uTG7vpsDs

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome developping tools (it's probably existing in others browsers) you can check what is the expiration date of your cookies.

You can access to this functionnalitie in the tab **Application** and on the left there is the label **Cookies** :

[image: Developping tools cookies vue]

Be carefull with the use of `$cookieStore` because [it's depreciated since v1.4.0](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)